# Only a few programs will launch without rebooting first

Tags: unity, 14.04, updates, launcher

I'm running 14.04 Trusty Tahr, and after a recent update my system has an issue (I want to be clear that I mess with settings a lot, so this may not be directly the fault of the update, but the problem didn't occur before then, and I don't recall making any other changes at the time).

The problem is that after loading up, Ubuntu will only open a few programs. After it has opened about 3-4, or after it has been running for a while, other programs will refuse to launch (even if all the current programs are closed. After closing they won't reopen.) Trying to launch them will sometimes result in a loading icon on the cursor, and other times, nothing. Strangely, this doesn't seem to affect synaptic package manager or nautilus, but does affect the terminal - which I have strong negative feelings about. It's a pain because I can't check to see if opening them from terminal will work.

I can switch programs by restarting my computer, but obviously this isn't an ideal solution. I should also mention I have a dual-boot, in case this has to do with memory.

Is this a known problem? Are other people experiencing it now?

Comment: Just rebooted. It doesn't have any trouble opening all of my programs at once. I have terminal open now, so when it decides to stop working again, I'll check if I can open things through that.

Comment: OP's answer clearly says it's a dupe of the target

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I stopped being useless and fixed the problem (kinda).

Attempts to open things via terminal gave an error stating "Maximum number of clients reached". It's a problem with X. I googled around and found this thread: [How can I diagnose/debug "maximum number of clients reached" X errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4499/how-can-i-diagnose-debug-maximum-number-of-clients-reached-x-errors) where someone had trouble with a wallpaper changer. I checked wallch, and sure enough it wasn't working. So I quit that, and ran something through terminal and the problem was fixed. Still not sure whether it was an update to x or wallch that caused the issue, but I don't really care.

Bleep bloop.